# How to decode some less common food Expiration Manufactured codes (US)?

Tags: baking, food-safety, food-preservation, chips, snacks

How do I decode these codes?

`206 X4A1 14:57` and `206V`

Comment: Welcome to the site, your question needs more details. What did you see these codes on, and why do you think they are to do with expiration?

Comment: They’re not ‘expiration’. They’re used for cycling stock, yes, but very few foods have true expirations. (Baby formula is one of the few).  Most of anything are ‘best by’ or ‘use by’ which is an indication that the product might change in texture, lose flavor, etc

Answer (score 2):

Those codes will typically indicate the production date and time of the product, not the expiration. Industry standard is to use [Julian date codes](https://people.biology.ucsd.edu/patrick/julian_cal.html).

For the information you provided:

- '206' may correspond to July 25,
- 'V' and 'X4A1' shifts/production lines,
- 14:57 the finished sealed package stamping time.

Potato chips will usually be manufactured for consumption within 1 year, and longer and quality would decline due to the oils oxidizing and becoming rancid.